# Inserted image unable to show in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
create table img(id integer primary key, image blob);     

insert into img 
value(1, load_file('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image/imge.png'));      

select * from img;
```

It's showing only the id column. The image column is null.

Answer (score 1):

your path is not correct - last slash should also be a backslash

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image\imge.png

also check:

1. the file must be located on the server host
2. you must have the FILE privilege
3. the file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes.
4. if the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.
5. The character_set_filesystem system variable controls interpretation of file names that are given as literal strings (default value - binary). For systems on which multibyte file names are permitted, a different value may be more appropriate. For example, if the system represents file names using UTF-8, set character_set_filesystem to 'utf8'.